# Is it possible to load html file to typescript as variable?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm using webpack and typescript.
Is it possible to load html file as variable?
Something like: `import myTemplate from './template.html';`

Comment: Can you just load the html file like any other file? e.g. `fs.readFile(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) webpack loader and if you import via `import myTemplate from './template.html'`, it should work.